# Other solutions don't work: "Invalid procedure call or argument" when setting a PivotTable

Tags: vba, excel

**Yes** I have searched for this issue, but none of the solutions I found fixed my error.

My program's goal is to generate a pivottable from a datasheet (ws), and create a pivotchart from that pivottable. It will be a macro used by co-workers, so I want it to work even in wierd situations (which is why i'm often referencing cells instead of a simple string, a string could be changed by the end user and then the program would break) There are a lot of errors in this program, but i'm able to fix most of them.

The only one which *keeps* coming back is "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument." For this code

```
Set pt = ws_pivot.PivotTables.Add( _
    PivotCache:=pc, _
    TableDestination:="'" & ws_pivot.Name & "'!" & ws_pivot.Range("A1").Address, _
    TableName:="pt" & Str(ActiveWorkbook.PivotTables.Count))
```

Within the Subroutine

```
Option Explicit
Sub VbaPivotReport2()

Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim ws As Worksheet 'Source worksheet, with data
Dim ws_pivot As Worksheet 'worksheet with PivotTable
Dim ch_pivot As Chart
Dim sh As Shape
Set ws = Worksheets("Waiting List Members")

'This checks for pre-existing pivot caches, creating a new one if there aren't any
If ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count = 0 Then
    Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
        SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:="'" & ws.Name & "'!" & ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address, _
        Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)
Else
    Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches(1)
End If

Set ws_pivot = Worksheets.Add
'Concatenating the name with a count makes each one unique, so there aren't duplicates
ws_pivot.Name = "Pivot_Report" & Str(Worksheets.Count - 1) 

Set pt = ws_pivot.PivotTables.Add( _
    PivotCache:=pc, _
    TableDestination:="'" & ws_pivot.Name & "'!" & ws_pivot.Range("A1").Address, _
    TableName:="pt" & Str(ActiveWorkbook.PivotTables.Count))

With pt.PivotFields("Length")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With

pt.AddDataField _
    pt.PivotFields("MonthsWaiting"), _
    Caption:="Avg Months Waiting", _
    Function:=xlAverage

'Below here is all formatting the PivotChart, making it look nice
pt.CompactLayoutRowHeader = "Length"
Range("A2").Group _
Start:=True, _
End:=True, _
By:=1
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.NumberFormat = "0.0"
Set sh = ws_pivot.Shapes.AddChart2( _
Style:=201, _
XlChartType:=xlColumnClustered)
ch_pivot = sh.Chart
ch_pivot.SetSourceData Source:=(ws_pivot.Range("A1").CurrentRegion)
ch_pivot.Legend.Delete
ch_pivot.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
Selection.Caption = "Boat Length Overall (LOA)"
ch_pivot.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
Selection.Caption = "LOA vs Average Months Waiting"

With ch_pivot.Axes(xlValue)
    .TickLables.NumberFormat = "0"
    .MajorUnit = 10
End With
With ch_pivot.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent2
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.6000000238
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With

End Sub
```

The solution I've seen is that the DestinationName needs apostrophes if it contains spaces: mine doesn't. I've also tried setting the table variable via

```
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(Destination, [Name], etc...)
```

And I get the same error.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why bother with `& Str(ActiveWorkbook.PivotTables.Count))` for the table name? the lines before it create the sheet that the table will be added to, so it's always going to be `0`

Comment: Instead of setting `TableDestination` to a `String`, just use `TableDestination:=ws_pivot.Range("A1")` and see if that works.

Comment: in addition to peter's method you could try `.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)`

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 's method should work

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 About the & Str(ActiveWorkbook.PivotTables.Count)), this is just a precaution for if the end user wants to use the same macro multiple times on different data sheets (all within the same workbook). Not certain about this but it should be useful in that case, as they create the second PivotTable the first will still exist, so its important to give them unique names.

Comment: @PeterT Thanks for that, it fixed the issue. Do you have any idea why returning a range (your method), and not a string (the Microsoft 'Official' recommendation), worked?